# Parse Cloud Code Define and Job in one JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, file, parse-platform, cloud, parse-cloud-code

I am running a few cloud code actions in my main.js file which is uploaded to Parse.com. I decided to add a `job` to my project so, just like all the other cloud code functions I am running in the main.js, I decided to write the job at the bottom of the file. All was well, it was successfully uploaded to the server, except one thing. When I went to schedule a job, it gave me the error, "You need to add a job in Cloud Code before you can schedule a job." Anyways, after trying a bunch of different solutions, and receiving no positive yield, I uploaded the job by itself. It worked perfectly and I was able to schedule just fine. What am I doing wrong in my code below to cause the jobs and the code functions to not all run in the same js file? 
I heard I might need to link the main.js to another js file by doing something like '`var abc = require('cloud/cloudFunctions.js');`'? Is that necessary?

Thanks

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("updateScore", function(request, response) {
      if (!request.user) {
        response.error("Must be signed in to call this Cloud Function.")
        return;
      }
      // Make sure to first check if this user is authorized to perform this change.
      // One way of doing so is to query an Admin role and check if the user belongs to that Role.
      // I've chosen to use a secret key. DO NOT use this method in a PUBLIC iOS app.
      if (request.params.secret != "code1234") {
        response.error("Not authorized.")
        return;    
      }

      // The rest of the function operates on the assumption that the request is *authorized*

      Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

      // Query for the user to be modified by objectId
      // The objectId is passed to the Cloud Function in a 
      // key named "objectId". You can search by email or
      // user id instead depending on your use case.

      var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
      query.equalTo("objectId", request.params.objectId);

      // Get the first user which matches the above constraints.
      query.first({
        success: function(anotherUser) {
          // Successfully retrieved the user.
          // Modify any parameters as you see fit.
          // You can use request.params to pass specific
          // keys and values you might want to change about
          // this user.
          anotherUser.set("totalScore", request.params.score);
          anotherUser.set("WorLStreak", request.params.worlstreak); 
          anotherUser.set("WorLNumber", request.params.worlnumber);
          anotherUser.set("FirstGoalName", request.params.firstGoalName);
          anotherUser.set("WinningTeamSelection", request.params.winningTeamSelection);

          // Save the user.
          anotherUser.save(null, {
            success: function(anotherUser) {
              // The user was saved successfully.
              response.success("Successfully updated user.");
            },
            error: function(gameScore, error) {
              // The save failed.
              // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
              response.error("Could not save changes to user.");
            }
          });
        },
        error: function(error) {
          response.error("Could not find user.");
        }
      });
    });

    Parse.Cloud.define("sendPushToUsers", function(request, response) {
     var message = request.params.message;
      var recipientUserId = request.params.recipientId;
       var channelId = request.params.channelId;

    if (!request.user) {
        response.error("Must be signed in to call this Cloud Function.")
        return;
      }
      // Make sure to first check if this user is authorized to perform this change.
      // One way of doing so is to query an Admin role and check if the user belongs to that Role.
      // I've chosen to use a secret key. DO NOT use this method in a PUBLIC iOS app.
      if (request.params.secret != "code4321") {
        response.error("Not authorized.")
        return;    
      }

      Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

      // Validate the message text.
      // For example make sure it is under 140 characters
      if (message.length > 140) {
      // Truncate and add a ...
        message = message.substring(0, 137) + "...";
      }

      // Send the push.
      // Find devices associated with the recipient user
      var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
      pushQuery.equalTo("channels", channelId);

      // Send the push notification to results of the query
      Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery,
        data: {
          alert: message
        }
      }).then(function() {
          response.success("Push was sent successfully.")
      }, function(error) {
          response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
      });
    });


    Parse.Cloud.define("sendPushToWinningUsers", function(request, response) {
     var message = request.params.message;
      var recipientUserId = request.params.recipientId;
       var userId = request.params.userId;

    if (!request.user) {
        response.error("Must be signed in to call this Cloud Function.")
        return;
      }
      // Make sure to first check if this user is authorized to perform this change.
      // One way of doing so is to query an Admin role and check if the user belongs to that Role.
      // I've chosen to use a secret key. DO NOT use this method in a PUBLIC iOS app.
      if (request.params.secret != "codeJob1234") {
        response.error("Not authorized.")
        return;    
      }

      Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

      // Validate the message text.
      // For example make sure it is under 140 characters
      if (message.length > 140) {
      // Truncate and add a ...
        message = message.substring(0, 137) + "...";
      }

      // Send the push.
      // Find devices associated with the recipient user
      var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
      pushQuery.equalTo("owner", userId);

      // Send the push notification to results of the query
      Parse.Push.send({
        where: pushQuery,
        data: {
          alert: message
        }
      }).then(function() {
          response.success("Push was sent successfully.")
      }, function(error) {
          response.error("Push failed to send with error: " + error.message);
      });
    });

    Parse.Cloud.job("gameTime", function(request, response) {
     var message = "It’s Game Time! Tune in for live scoring updates!";

      Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
      var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
      pushQuery.equalTo("channels", "PreGameNotifications");

  Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: {
      alert: message
    }
  });


      var query = new Parse.Query("Score");
      // query.equalTo("objectId", “”);

      // Get the first user which matches the above constraints.
      query.first({
        success: function(anotherUser) {

          anotherUser.set("isGameTime", "YES");

          // Save the user.
          anotherUser.save(null, {
            success: function(anotherUser) {
              response.success("Successfully updated user.");
            },
            error: function(gameScore, error) {
              response.error("Could not save changes to user.");
            }
          });
        },
        error: function(error) {
          response.error("Could not find user.");
        }
      });
    });
```

Comment: Try to clean your code, fix indentation and add semicolon, track bug syntax. You call `response.success()` multiple times in your job task, after the push callback your job stop.

Comment: @Bluety What do you mean by "fix indentation and add semicolon"? Where should I add one?

Comment: I think a syntax error like semicolon forgot at end line can cause the problem. Have you test your code with jslint ? Or the multiple call to `response.success()`.

Comment: I updated my question.. even after removing the first response.success(), still nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have try your code and it works fine.

You need to follow this steps:
https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#started-setup

Add your code to the main.js file and deploy. After that, you can schedule a job.

Comment: Yes thank you it does work! The reason it would not allow me to load the new job, and the reason it said I have no jobs in my cloud code, was because it was an error message telling me I could only have 1 parse cloud code with my basic account. Thank you though!